# Using jQuery FeedEk Plugin and SharePoint 2013 RSS feeds

Tags: jquery, rss, sharepoint-2013

I'm attempting to use JQuery 1.9.1 and the FeedEk RSS plugin to read an RSS feed from an internal company Sharepoint 2013 blog site. However, the feed is coming back as `NULL`. Anyone ever encountered this, and know of a workaround? The code works just fine if I change the `FeedUrl` to any other `rss`, such as CNN.

```
<div id="blogcontent"></div>
<script src="/scripts/jquery.1.9.2.js"></script>
<script src="/scripts/jquery.feedek.js"></script>
<script language="Javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#blogcontent').FeedEk({
            FeedUrl: 'http://[internal_SP_site_address]/Blog/_layouts/listfeed.aspx?List={58FB902D-E2AF-431A-87E2-D8F789728AFE}',
            MaxCount: 5
        });

    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Realized that FeedEk is using the Google Feeds API, so I'm not able to pass a RSS feed from behind our firewall to it. Guess I'll be looking to build my own parser...